# How can I use a system environment variable with CSpyBat

Tags: iar

I use C-SPY macros for automated testing. For this purpose I load a startup macro file and it loads additional macro files using the following code:

```
execUserSetup()
{
  __registerMacroFile("$_ENVVAR_$\\macros-1.mac");
  __registerMacroFile("$_ENVVAR_$\\macros-2.mac");
  ...
}
```

This works like a charm when I run the startup macro from within the *IAR Embedded Workbench*.

But what I really want to do is running the tests with CSpyBat.exe. There I specify my startup.mac using the option `--macro startup.mac`.

The files `macros-1.mac` and so on won't be found then. Instead I get error messages for the macro files (with garbage file names, see below):

> ERROR: Could not open macro file: @۸0ٸ`ٸ@2@u

If I use the pathnames without the environment variables, everything is okay.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: The workbench supports expanding environment or project variables, but CSpyBat doesn't. So told me IAR support. Also they gave me the following pointer:

See 'C-SPY Debugging Guide' - "Using C-SPY in batch mode", "INVOCATION SYNTAX", page 492:

> Note: In those cases where a filename is required—including the DLL files—you are
>   recommended to give a full path to the filename.